# Cassandra Isolation -- update visibility to other clients

Tags: cassandra

The [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlTransactionsDiffer.html) says "This means that a write to a row within a single partition on a single node is only visible to the client performing the operation".

If there is another client2 perform operations on the same partition and on the same single node, is the write being performed by "THE CLIENT" as mentioned in the doc, also visible to this client2?

And, what does "visible to the client performing the operation" actually mean?

More concrete examples would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This means that when you're making change, data is written atomically inside partition - the client2 won't see the part of the row, only the full row, or nothing.